# Minting/Sending 0 Value ERC-20 Tokens in Response to Transaction in Another Contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, mint

I currently have a working ERC-20 contract for a small group that I am in. I would like to make a new contract that mints or sends a 0 value token without liquidity similar to a rewards token that has defined parameters; Qty token to send is equal to X in reference to the other token quantity specified. I am familiar with reflection/taxation contracts, but I am unsure how to add a 0 value token from a contract to match parameters on the users transaction on token A. Supply would be controlled so not a concern for minting/burning.

I have thought about how this would be done with the minter/parser contract, again just not quite sure how to match parameters. If there was a way to add this to the original contract being a 0 value token it would pull from I would be interested in how that would be done. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tend to not explain things clear enough, so if 50 tokens are sent of token A, I would like to send 50 tokens of 0 value of token B in another contract.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating both token A and token B, just token B, or neither? It sounds to me like you're creating both of them?

Correct me if I'm wrong here, but to sum up it sounds like you're creating contracts for ERC20 tokenA and ERC20 tokenB, and whenever an amount of tokenA is transferred, you want the same amount of tokenB to be transferred to the same address?

If so you can simply give tokenA mint privileges over tokenB and add the following line to tokenA's transfer(sender, recipient, amount) function:

```
tokenB.mint(recipient, amount);
```

Comment: Yes that is correct, I am creating Token A and Token B. I have created Token A already and it is deployed, working etc. I do not mind having to do the contract again for Token A, so that is no issue.

So essentially add that to Token A, allow it mint privileges over Token B, a function to set and define what Token B is (if not hard coded), then set the amount equal to Token A to be deployed correct?

Comment: The ratio/percentage for tokenB minted could then be further defined in another identifier I am assuming?

Comment: Yeah that's one way to do it, it has its pros and cons. Not knowing more about what you're trying to do it's hard to say that would be the best way--you'd never be able to unseparate tokenA and tokenB, and it would be forever be more gas expensive to transfer tokenA. But yeah this way would work.

Comment: Great thank you! Essentially I am trying to just send "Proof of Activity" in a X:1 ratio of the native token that will remain with the user throughout their participation. Would another ERC type reduce gas fees? Or another way to call the mint?

Comment: I wouldn't even use an ERC20 in that case; I'd add it to the first ERC20 and just have the 1 contract. You can just have a mapping of address => uint inside the native token that is incremented each time the token is transferred. ERC20 has a lot of functionality that will make incrementing and deploying much more expensive if you never plan on letting users transfer this proof of activity. If they should be able to transfer it though, ERC20 is fine.

Comment: I am using the following code, and receive the error that follows it: 'function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external override returns (bool) {  theTokenFinal.mint(recipient, amountFinal);/br return _transferFrom(msg.sender, recipient, amount); } ''' ``` lang-all DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. --> V4tst.sol:538:9: | 538 | theTokenFinal.mint(recipient, amountFinal); | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ' Everything has been defined; it works if i comment the mint line out. Any advice with this? All I have left. –

Comment: So I'm guessing that all this code is inside tokenA, and theTokenFinal is tokenB? mint() will only work if theTokenFinal is cast as an ERC20. I'm not sure that making it an ERC20 makes sense (since it sounds like you're not actually planning on users being able to transfer it?) but either way I think that's your problem. I can help you more if you provide more code.

Comment: That is correct, all of that code is nested in TokenA, while TokenB has not been created yet, so that way could easily build it around what i need for A. If ERC-20 for TokenB is going to make it more difficult overall, and TokenB is still able to be seen externally, then I am definitely willing to explore that. Would a ERC-777 or 1155? I am going to attach the code in an additional comment, but please bare with me as I do not frequent forums often so I do not know how to make it look like code (been trying several the markdowns). Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please see link below for the transfer functions and additional information I just put on Git. If additional information is needed please let me know and I will supply the information much quicker; I have been made more available over the next several days. Thank you again for your continued help!

https://github.com/jtbitz/Testing/blob/main/Testing.sol

Comment: OK so is tokenB an address or an ERC20 in your code? Solidity won't recognize function calls unless you're calling an interface with that function, so you need to import the IERC20 interface and then cast tokenB's address as an IERC20 for mint() to work, like so: IERC20(tokenB).mint().

Comment: However that's not the best way to do this since making tokenB an ERC20 at all would be pretty inefficient and also allow users to trade tokenB. You're best off just putting tokenB inside tokenA and just having one contract--an ERC20 that also tracks token movement. You can do that using a public mapping (address => uint256) and incrementing the uint256 when appropriate.

Comment: Thank you Meriadoc, you made me realize I was not calling the ERC20MinterPauser in front of the token: ERC20PresetMinterPauser(tokenB).mint(). It all compiles fine now finally. Now to test functionality to see if it is correct.